# Upgraded to 4.6.7 and now the Register links in the Upcoming Events list block have a typo

Tags: civievent, registration, links

We upgraded from 4.6.6 to 4.6.7 on Drupal6, and now the register links in the Upcoming Events block go to /civicrm/event/register?rest=1&id= (as shown in the screen shot below), instead of civicrm/event/register?reset=1&id=, creating redirect problems for potential patrons.

[image: Screen shot]

I am not sure in which file I would find the code to correct. Please help!!

Comment: It turns out that somehow the Views file got altered during the upgrade. I corrected the output in Views and that solved the problem. I figured I'd leave this up in case anyone else experiences a similar issue.

Comment: If possible, please post an answer that tells others what you did (and mark your own answer as the correct one). This helps future searchers find the question and the resolution.

Answer (score 1):

In Views, I went to Edit view civicrm_events, Events List view.

Click on field CiviCRM Events: Start Date.
Under Rewriting, select the checkbox Output this field as link and make sure it is corrected to [yoursite]/civicrm/event/register?reset=1&id=[id]. Then click Update and Save.